# Update the code that uses DirectX 9 for Windows 8 Store (SafeSEH flag)

Tags: windows-8, directx, windows-store-apps, compatibility

I have working app that uses `DirectX 9`. I need to update my app for `Windows 8 Store` that require compilation with `SafeSEH` flag. It's working only with `DirectX 11 SDK`, but there is no `d3dx9` that used by my app. I was found `DirectXTK`, `DirectXTex` and `DirectXMath` libs with similar functionality. What is best way to update the code with no damage to older platforms (that have only old version of `DirectX 9` runtime) ?

Comment: Well I see some ambiguity. You want a Windows 8 StoreApp, but compatible with old runtime? But you cannot run it on Windows XP!

Comment: I wanted to use `DirectX 9`, but now see the only one way - rewriting all in `DirectX 11`

Comment: D3D11 API is not so scarry beast. It is pleasure to work with! BTW, I am not sure, but is this possible to create d3d9 device for CoreWindow (not hWnd) at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the `DirectX 9` code must be rewriten with `DirectX 11`, cause `DirectXTK`, `DirectXTex`, `DirectXMath` libs works only with DX11. More information I have found at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wingameswithdirectx/thread/c082b208-0d95-4c41-852f-9450340093f4/